# What if an opened file gets modified? Python

Tags: python

Lets say I opened a file in python using

```
file = open("abc.txt",'rb')
```

I read 1024 bytes from file using

```
data = file.read(1024)
```

and the file abc.txt gets modified.
So now if I try to read more data which version of the file will it read(the one before opening or the new modified one)?

Comment: Well, when you tested this by opening a file, and having another process modify that file, what did you find?

Comment: I tested it on text file. It ignored the modification, just kept on reading from original file.

Comment: @KartarSingh: How did you modify the file? Many editors use a strategy of write-to-temp, atomic rename, which wouldn't modify the file an open handle refers to. Editing the file in place might behave differently (or might not, depending on buffering behavior).

Comment: While testing I used vim, text editor.

Comment: @ksmukta: Yup, that would do it. `vim` uses the write-to-temp, atomic rename approach; you kept the handle to the original file (which continues to exist until the last handle is closed, but without a name on the file system). If you want to test, make some other file, and just append it to the open file with `cat otherfile >> openfilename`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger using echo "newtext" >> openedfile, now the new data is also being read in the opened file.